# Strategy for board game

Tags: combinatorics

> Alice and Bob are playing the following game:
>   They have a 4x4 empty grid and take turns coloring one square each, starting with Alice, both using the same color.
>   Whoever completes any 2x2 area on the grid (after having made his move) is the loser. Is there any winning strategy for any of the two players?

I have played the game several times and can't see a clear strategy for any of the two. It seems to me that Bob will loose.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Preechapak Tekasuk are A and B using the same colour?

Comment: @giannispapav Yes.

Comment: @PreechapakTekasuk You  should make this clear in the question.  I interpreted it the same way that Ronald Blake did, that they were using different colors.

Comment: There *is* a winning strategy. There's no possible draw, so it must be unfair. See Wolfram for unfair games.

Comment: Then Bob can easily force a win.

Comment: @saulspatz Thank you! Just posted an edit.

Comment: A board with only losing moves either had $11$ or $12$ squares filled. If it has $11$ squares filled in, then after rotation, the squares $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are open. So Bob can force a win by playing one of the edge-squares (i.e. squares adjacent to an edge, but not at a corner) in each quadrant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If Alice selects a square $(i,j)$, Bob should choose $(i+2,j)$. In this way he will never complete a square before Alice does, and hence Bob will always win. Of course, modulo 4 is required with this strategy.

Likewise a strategy $(i,j+2)$ would have worked. Note that these strategies are always possible, because they fill the full grid with particular pairs.

In the case of a $n \times n$ grid for odd values of $n=2 m + 1$, there is a winning strategy for Alice. If she starts with $(m,m)$ as the first square and responds to any choice $(i,j)$ of Bob by playing $(2 m -i,2 m-j)$, Bob will make the first $2\times2$ square. This approach can also be generalised to rectangular grids, and will result in a winning strategy for Alice when both dimensions are odd.

Thanks to @Philip for pointing out that the pairing $(i,j)$ and $(i+2,j+2)$ would not work in the $4\times4$ grid, because the choosing of the 4 corners by Alice would create a central square made by Bob.

Thanks to @Carmeister for pointing out that a generalisation for even values $n=2m$ by pairing  the square $(i,j)$ of Alice by Bob taking $(i+m,j)$, would also not be successful for the same reason. By choosing suitable squares (this time not the corners) Alice could force Bob to make a central square as well if he would stick to this particular strategy.

So the question of the existence/absence of a winning strategy for even sided square grids larger than $4\times4$ is still open.

Comment: What if Alice plays something on the right hand edge of the grid?

Comment: @JackM The $+2$ is mod 4.

Comment: What if there is no i+2?

Comment: very nice @Ronald Blaak

Comment: So if Alice selects (4, 1), what does Bob select? (2,1)?

Comment: Note that this works because the element $(2, 0)$ is of order two in the group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, which implies that Bob never risks having to play on a square Alice already played on. On say, a $5\times 5$ grid, I'm not sure how to generalize this.

Comment: @JackM this was my next question! Can you please explain what "order two" means?

Comment: @PreechapakTekasuk It means $(2, 0) + (2, 0) = (0, 0)$, and more importantly $-(2, 0)=(2,0)$

Comment: It generalizes to a rectangular grid, if one of the dimensions is even.

Comment: For odd $n$, Alice seems to have a winning strategy. She starts by coloring the center square and then mirrors Bob's moves thereafter.

Comment: So you mean that if Alice selects, say, (1,1) then Bob will play (3,1), if Alice selects (3,1), Bob will play (1,1) and if she plays (4,1), Bob will play (2,1)?

Comment: @Jens Again, this generalizes to rectangular grids, so it appears that the problem is solved for all rectangular grids.  Alice wins if both dimensions are odd, and Bob wins otherwise.

Comment: @Philip : Yes you are right, I overlooked that one.

Comment: @PreechapakTekasuk Yes, and the important point is that Alice can't make Bob play a square that she's already played. If the square she played is $a$ then she would have to play $a-(2,0)$, but that equals $a+(2,0)$ because $(2,0)=-(2,0)$, and that's the square Bob played already the last time Alice played $a$.

Comment: @RonaldBlaak Alice's strategy works for $n=4$ now after the edit, but the generalization to bigger even grids still fails in the case philip mentioned in his comment. Still, nice answer! +1

Comment: @Carmeister, your right. I have been spending too much time on periodic boundaries which are absent here.

Comment: I think $(n-i,n-j)$ should be $(n+1-i,n+1-j)$?

Comment: Assuming the grid is indexed beginning at 0, couldn't Alice play in squares (0,0), (0,1), (3,0), and (3,1)? This would leave Bob choosing (2,0), (2,1), (1,0), and (1,1) respectively, creating a square.

Comment: @PiGuy34 Yes that would be a valid game. However, in your suggested game play  Bob would unnecessarily loose the game when he makes a square on his 4th move, because there are other moves he could choose.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it Alice wins the first time. Because the 'one square' she colours can be any size 2by 2, 3by 3 or 4by 4, she doesn't get a 2nd chance to colour.

Comment: Whoever completes a 2x2 square is the *loser* so even if Alice were permitted to colour a 2x2 square (or larger) she wouldn't. I think you have not interpreted the question correctly.