# Strategy for board game 2

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, combinatorial-game-theory

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2884764/strategy-for-board-game) the following was asked:

> Alice and Bob are playing the following game: They have a $4 \times 4$ empty grid and take turns coloring one square each, starting with Alice, both using the same color. Whoever completes any $2 \times 2$ area on the grid (after having made their move) is the loser. Is there any winning strategy for any of the two players?

The answer was that Bob had a winning strategy (see link). It was also determined that for an $n \times n$ grid, where $n$ is odd, Alice has a winning strategy. However, it was not determined who has a winning strategy when $n$ is even with $n \gt 4$.

Can someone spot such a strategy?

**Edit**

To avoid repeats of answers previously given, here are two strategies for Bob which don't work:

1. Bob's winning strategy for $n=4$

   If Alice colors $(i,j)$, Bob colors $(1+(i+m-1) \mod n, \ j)$, where $n=2m$. Won't work for $n \gt 4$ as Alice can color e.g. $(1,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(n,1)$, $(n,2)$.
2. Bob mirror's Alice's move

   If Alice colors $(i,j)$, Bob colors $(n+1-i, n+1-j)$. Won't work as Alice can color two adjacent central squares.

In fact, I think Alice might have a winning strategy. I simulated $10,000$ games on a $6 \times 6$ grid where each player made random "legal" moves, i.e. moves which don't immediately result in a loss, and Alice consistently wins $56 \text {%}$ of the time.

Comment: This belongs on the Puzzles stack exchange... not here.

Comment: This seems to fall under the "combinatorial game theory" tag.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I disagree -- combinatorial games like this are absolutely in scope for this site

Comment: How does Alice winning consistently $56\%$ of the time differ from Alice winning $56\%$ of the time?

Comment: @joriki No special meaning. I just ran it a couple of times with a $1000$ games, then ran it with $10,000$ games and the result was every time $56 \%$.

Comment: @Jens My computer-based search of the $6\times 6$ board agrees with your statistical estimate and unless I made a mistake (which *is* quite possible), Alice really has a winning strategy. I don't have any compact description of it yet, but it seems that if she avoids playing the four corners of the central $4\times 4$ square (i.e. $(2,2)$, $(2,5)$, $(5,2)$ and $(5,5)$ when numbering the rows and columns $1-6$), her chances in the "random" play you described climb up to $64%$. In fact, the search suggests she *must* avoid playing those four places on her first move, but can play any other.

Comment: @Peter Košinár Thanks for confirming my simulation result. I tried your strategy of avoiding those squares on Alice's first move, but still get $56\%$. Could you doublecheck?

Comment: @Jens The "improved" strategy for Alice was to avoid those squares on all of her turns (i.e.if there is at least one other valid move, she should not fill any of those squares). The "first" move remark was related only to a perfect opponent: it seems that if she opens the game with one of those squares, Bob could use it to his advantage if he knew how.

Comment: @Peter Košinár Understood. And I can confirm your result. Before reading your newest comment, I was inspired by your statistical analysis of Alice's first move and did my own analysis. I found that if Alice's first move was one of the four central squares, her winning percentage rises to $58\%$. If I combine this with your constraint, her winning percentage is around $68\%$!

Comment: @Peter Košinár On a $6 \times 6$ grid, a simulation of 300,000 random games indicates that Alice's best first move is a central square. If her first move is set to one of those squares, e.g. $(3,3)$, a further 300,000 simulations indicate that her best second move is $(4,3)$. If that move isn't possible, her second best move is $(1,3)$. Using your constraint for the rest of the game, 10,000 simulations give her a winning percentage of $73\%$.

Answer (score -3):

Simulating random games tells nothing about whether or not a winning strategy exists.  However, as the maximum number of moves before the game ends results in Bob losing (a maximum of 27 out of the 36 squares can be colored without coloring in any 2x2 square).  As a result, as long as Alice can force the game to go the maximum number of moves, she wins.